# How to make UITextView Programmatically using Core Graphics?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

How to draw textview using core graphics to equally balance the load between Cpu and Gpu to achieve a good fps ? (Smooth Scrolling)

i am using tableview and making cell Programmatically ,  assigning textview on that but when scrolling fps drop down to 15-18 fps .

Steps tried :-
Data Binding @ willDisplayCell,
Setting Opaque and alpha of view,
Making Cell Programmatically Adding constraint Programmatically,
Using autolayout.
So Any Suggestions Would Be Welcome

Cell Code And setting data at cellforrow at indexpath

```
class progCell: UITableViewCell {
let textView: UITextView = UITextView()
      override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

         super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        textView.textColor = UIColor.black
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.dataDetectorTypes = .all
        self.contentView.addSubview(textView)



        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: textView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: textView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: textView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: textView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        self.contentView.addConstraints([leadingConstraint,trailingConstraint,topConstraint,bottomConstraint])

    }
```

CellForRow Code

```
   var cell: NameDefaultCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WithName, for: indexPath) as? NameDefaultCell
 self.TextView?.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: model.message)
```

Comment: @AshleyMills  Posted  The Code

Comment: Please post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code

Comment: It's very likely that your FPS drops because you do CPU intensive stuff on the main thread (e.g. loading data for the cell). Just putting a text view into a cell won't create a laggy UI.

Comment: @AshleyMills Posted the code

Comment: @Wukerplank not Doing Anything On main thread and putting textview and adding attributed text is causing lag .

Comment: Why are you creating an `NSMutableAttributedString` with no attributes and then setting the text view's `attributedText` property? Why not directly set `model.message` to the `text` property?

Comment: Is `model.message` a computed or a stored property?

Comment: Taking Our string from model.message . Its computed for each message @AshleyMills